# Flask check where a request comes from

Tags: python, http, heroku, flask

I'm new to flask and am trying to find out where certain HTTP requests are coming from. I have an API sending out requests to my server and I need to verify it was my API and not some random post. How can I check where an HTTP request comes from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flask's [request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#the-request-object) object contains remote_addr, which is the address of the client. Alternatively, `request` also contains the WSGI `environ` dictionary, which is defined in [PEP 033](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/). In the environ dictionary, there is a REMOTE_ADDR key which contains the same data:

```
request.remote_addr
request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

If you're worried you might be getting data from that IP address, but you still want to form a distinction between your API and some other source, you can include another header in your API's request and access it by the request object

```
request.headers.get(header_name)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Super helpful.